# Fail to change the HDMI display resolution on iMx6 board

Tags: linux, qt, imx6

I am working on embedded product that runs on Embedded Linux & Qt Framework developed to run on i.Mx6 custom board that we built. We have LVDS display interface which is set at 1366x768 resolution.

```
/ # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
U:1380x768p-59
```

Now I am trying to interface the display on HDMI and am noticing that the resolution on HDMI monitor is not getting set properly it shows 1280x1024.

```
/ # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
V:1280x1024p-60
```

I have tried to interrupt the boot process and tried to force the resolution by running the below step and proceed to boot

> U-Boot > set hdmi_video video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1366x768M@60,if=RGB24
>   fbmem=10M,28M vmalloc=400M

I noticed that the resolution was not being set again. I confirmed that by running below commands:

> / # cat /proc/cmdline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 console=ttymxc2,115200
>   rootwait fixrtc consoleblank=0 lpj=7905280
>   video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1366x768M@60,if=RGB24 fbmem=10M,28M vmalloc=400M
>   uboot_version=01.00.00
>
> / # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode U:1280x720p-60

What ever the resolution I try the -xres was being forced to 1280 on the monitor I am using. I verified that my monitor supports the resolutions till **1680x1050**.

I tried the below option:

```
fbset -xres 1366 -yres 768 -match
```

But, that made the screen to go blank and doing `cat` on `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode` showed nothing.

All the options am trying to change the resolution were not working fine. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind do remove the horizontal scrollbars. It would improve the readability. Btw. I think this question should be better posted on superuser.com .

Comment: Thanks. I posted it on superuser.com too, am waiting for the help. Do you feel the tags I added to this question seems relevant for greater visibility of the question ?